# IllegalThreadStateException on Thread Start

Tags: java, multithreading

Some of my users have been reporting IllegalThreadStateExceptions, which lead back to the following code. I was unable to recreate it, and most people are able to execute this part of the code with no issues.

The code is re-executed periodically, so the old thread should be replaced by a new one and started, but that's where the error occurs.

```
if (head.threadSeal != null)
{
    head.threadSeal.interrupt();
}

head.threadSeal = new ThreadFindSeal();
head.threadSeal.start(); // IllegalThreadStateException here
```

Relevant stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:704)
```

Am I missing something in the documentation, why would start ever fail on a new thread?

Comment: What is a `ThreadFindSeal`?

Comment: I suspect a race condition on `head.threadSeal`, possibly by executing that code block simultaneously in multiple threads.

Comment: Any reason why you do not use an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: It's my subclass of thread. https://github.com/micdoodle8/Galacticraft/blob/master/common/micdoodle8/mods/galacticraft/core/oxygen/ThreadFindSeal.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of `Thread#start()` states

> Throws: **IllegalThreadStateException** - if the thread was already
>   started.

You haven't give much information, but the following could happen.

First thread executes

```
head.threadSeal = new ThreadFindSeal();
```

Second thread then executes

```
head.threadSeal = new ThreadFindSeal();
head.threadSeal.start();
```

replacing the `Thread` and starting it.

The first thread then executes

```
head.threadSeal.start();
```

which is called on the same `Thread` object as before, which was already started.